# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint error while uploading a backup of psql from previous server

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I recently changed my server hence I created a backup of psql database. In the new server is I used the
`psql dbname < dbname.bak` 
to backup  my database. Even though the django files (including migrations)(it was identical) were exactly the same, the backup process showed some errors, but somehow the backup succeeded. 
Every thing is working fine but the problem is when I am creating a new Model (example):

```
class StudentRoutineInformation(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    wakeTime = models.TimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    sleepTime = models.TimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    hoursaStudy = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
    favoriteSubject = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length = 255)
    examDate = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length = 255)
    examType = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length = 255)
    location = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length = 255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.name
```

When I do makemigrations it succeeds but during migration it shows this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_migrations_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(121) already exists.
```

Using other answers from stackoverflow I tried this:

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset MyApp | python manage.py dbshell
```

but this also shows an error:

```
ERROR:  relation "basicinformation_studentroutineinformation" does not exist
LINE 1: ...alesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "basicinfo...
```

The problem is now I can't make any models in any app. Same error in all the apps.
What might be the solution?
And what could have gone wrong during the backup because the models are same in both the servers, then what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your primary key sequences have desynchronized at some point. There have been issues with older versions of postgres not carrying over sequence positions when restoring from a backup, but. I don't think that's your issue as the violation is at id=121 not 1.

I'd recommend resetting your pk sequence positions manually by running:

```sql
SELECT
   setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('django_migrations', 'id'), max("id"))
FROM
   "django_migrations";
```

I would also check the `django_migrations` table to make sure all your migrations look correct, i.e. nothing missing/things that shouldn't be there.

Then also check your other models and make sure you can insert new rows. If you get more unique constraint violations on pk, then run the same SQL script on the other tables.